# On click of button,open selected row value to new window Jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get selected row id on the next page.I have a `checkbox` to select row items, after selecting it, on click of open button, the values should be populated on new window.

button code:

```html
<div class=" btn-default btn-block">
  <button href="#" id="view">View</button>
</div>
```

jquery for click:

```js
$('#view').on('click', function(e) {
  console.log(" view button clicked..");
});
```

Populate data in grid:

```js
function getTableData(data) {
  $.each(data, function(ind, obj){
    check for few conditions
  }
  $('#'+datagrid).dataTable().fnAddData( [
    "id:"+obj.id,                                           
    obj.name,
    obj.id,
    obj.phone
  ]);
  $('#grid').show();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors while doing so?

Comment: @trytocode do you have any sort of control over the screen opened in new window?

Comment: hi -OnClick of Checkbox selecting row and Open the Row on Button Click with existing data. this is my requirement. above code is my setup so far to retrieve data into table. Can you please suggest